# Missing Boostrap scss files in Svelte App

Tags: svelte, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to use Bootstrap with Svelte.  I have based the page structure on this Bootstrap example, however the resulting layout is way off with the style not really being applied.

I can see that styles defined in a scss folder within docs/5.2/dist are not being applied, as if those styles are not in the minified css I am referring to.

In `<head>`

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

In `<body>`

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

My full app is here https://github.com/ChrisWoodsSays/CyclingViewer

I have tried installing bootstrap via NPM and referring those files.

I have also seen https://sveltestrap.js.org/.  Is the latter a better option?  If so, I can investigate that.

Comment: Why do you use scss from `5.2` but have the js from `3.3.7` ? Version 5 of BS doesn't need jQuery no more. Also don't use jQuery `1.12.4` this is super old.

Comment: ah ha!  I was looking at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/ which is clearly out of date.